# How can I add a delay to a mouse click in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm attempting to make a store in my game, but am having issues with pygame.mouse.get_pressed(). When the user clicks on a button, the program thinks that they clicked on it more than once, therefore using more credits than the user intended. I would like to add a delay so that the game doesn't do this. I would like 1 click to represent them buying one object. I have tried reducing the framerate for that window, but the result is the same. Here is the code I currently have.

This is where all the mouse action occurs.

```
def button(x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action = None):
    global paused

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x, y, w, h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action == Game:
            Game()
        if click[0] == 1 and action == quitgame:
            sys.exit()
        if click[0] == 1 and action == None:
            paused = False
        if click[0] == 1 and action == StartScreen:
            save()
            StartScreen()
        if click[0] == 1 and action == LootScreen:
            LootScreen()
        if click[0] == 1 and action == open_common_drop:
            open_common_drop()
        if click[0] == 1 and action == open_rare_drop:
            open_rare_drop()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x, y, w, h))
```

This is where the loot store is currently at.

```
def LootScreen():
    global current_drops

    loot = True

    while loot:
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                save()

                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_t:
                    open_common_drop()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_y:
                    open_rare_drop()

                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    StartScreen()

        gameDisplay.fill(gray)
        title('Loot Chests!')

        button(400, 150, 260, 50, blue, bright_blue, open_common_drop)
        button(695, 150, 260, 50, red, bright_red, open_rare_drop)
        button(display_width * 0.42, display_height / 1.15, 255, 50, red, bright_red, StartScreen)

        game_display_text('Open Common Chest (T)', 407, 165)
        game_display_text('Open Rare Chest (Y)', 725, 165)
        game_display_text('You Got: %s' % current_drops, 50, display_height / 2)
        game_display_text('Credits: %.2f' % player_loot_data['credit_count'], 15, 15)
        game_display_text('Main Menu', display_width * 0.47, display_height / 1.13)

        game_display_text('Janus\': %s' % player_loot_data['loot_data_one'] , 950, 500)
        game_display_text('Peace of Minds: %s' % player_loot_data['loot_data_two'], 950, 535)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a bool switch in your button function. Here I re-worked the function in a way that should work.

```
def button(x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action = None, held):
    global paused

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x, y, w, h))

        if click[0] == 1:
            if held == False:
                if action == Game:
                    Game()
                elif action == quitgame:
                    sys.exit()
                elif action == None:
                    paused = False
                elif action == StartScreen:
                    save()
                    StartScreen()
                elif action == LootScreen:
                    LootScreen()
                elif action == open_common_drop:
                    open_common_drop()
                elif action == open_rare_drop:
                    open_rare_drop()
            held = True
        else:
            held = False

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x, y, w, h))
    return held
```

As you see, there is a new variable `held` added to the function to process whether the button is held or not. Held is taken and returned here, so it won't reset every time the function is called.

With that down, let me show you why I wrote it that way, and just how this logic works at its core.

```
import pygame
#
display = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#
held = False # Variable to handle if mouse button is held
#
RUNNING = True
while RUNNING:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            RUNNING = False
    #
    button = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() # Get mouse state
    if button[0]: # Check if left mouse button is pressed
        if held == False: # Check if button is held down
            print(True) # If button is not held down, print true
        held = True # Set held eqaual to true for next iteration
    else: # If left mouse button is not pressed
        held = False # held is set to false, alowing event to happen again
    #
    display.fill((0,0,0))
    #
    pygame.display.flip()
#
pygame.quit()
```

The above is a very simple stand alone program that also implements the held variable to monitor if the mouse button is held. In this program, the variable `held` is first declared as `False` as the mouse is not being pressed. Then, within the main loop, `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` is called to get the mouse input, and is immediately followed by a check for the left mouse button. If the left mouse button is pressed, a check for `held` will happen. If it is false, the program will print `True`. `held` is then set to `True` for the next iteration. The `else:` statement will fire if the left mouse button is not held down and reset `held` to its default `False` state.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a timed bool switch. Here's an example that should help out.

```
import time

boolswitch = False
timer = 0.0
clock = time.time()
x = time

while True:
    if timer > 0.25:
        boolswitch = True
        timer = 0.0
    else:
        x = time.time()
        timer += (x-clock)
        clock = x

    if boolswitch:
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if click[0] == 1:
            boolswitch = False
            clock = time.time()
```

Comment: I tried to incorporate this into my button(), but it resulted in my game black screening and becoming unresponsive.

Comment: That's because it's a while loop without a break condition in it. This is just an example of how timed bool switches work. You'd have to work the logic into your game's while loop.

Comment: I'll try to figure out how to make this work for my game. I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

oxrock's answer is definitely wrong, I know this post was made 7 years ago, but for the people that stumble upon this post, refer to this post:
https://python-forum.io/thread-23993.html

The `time.time()` function is performed synchronously, hence the program pauses.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34623013)

Comment: Please include the answer from the link instead of just providing the link.

Answer (score 0):

**Using a global variable and tracking the FPS**

You can perhaps use the fps and the amount of frames that pass, as a reference, to limit the amount of times the button detects itself being clicked. One possible way, is by defining a global variable that counts the number of frames that have passed since the previous click(namely, `FRAMES`) -:

```
FRAMES = 0
```

Furthermore, you can update this alongside the screen in your gameloop, but for that you need to also mention to python that it's a global variable.

```
global current_drops, FRAMES
```

---

```
FRAMES += 1
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(30)
```

The button function can then also use this as a global variable by mentioning the same -:

```
global paused, FRAMES
```

Following which, the click checking conditions can be surrounded by an if statement that checks whether `FRAMES >= (FPS / 2)`, to get fps we can use the `get_fps()` method of `clock`. Furthermore, to reset the frames incase the button is clicked again, we can set the FRAMES count to zero, like so -:

```
if click[0] == 1 and FRAMES == (clock.get_fps() / 2) :
    FRAMES = 0
    if action == Game:
        Game()
    if action == quitgame:
        sys.exit()
    if action == None:
        paused = False
    if action == StartScreen:
        save()
        StartScreen()
    if action == LootScreen:
        LootScreen()
    if action == open_common_drop:
        open_common_drop()
    if action == open_rare_drop:
        open_rare_drop()
```

The condition can further be modified and played around with, to suit the amount of delay you want.

---

**Using classes**

Note that, this approach can be further improved and the usage of a global variable can be prevented by perhaps defining a button class to achieve the functionality of a button, instead of just a function. Somewhat like so -:

```
class Button() :
    def __init__(self, width, height, inactive_color, active_color, action) :
        self.width, self.height, self.inactive_color, self.active_color, self.action = width, height, inactive_color, active_color, action
        self.button_frames = 0
        return
    
    def render(self, surface, x, y, clock) :
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    
        if x + self.width > mouse[0] > x and y + self.height > mouse[1] > y:
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.active_color, (x, y, self.width, self.height))
            
            if click[0] == 1 and self.button_frames >= (clock.get_fps() / 2) :
                self.action()
                self.button_frames = 0
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.inactive_color, (x, y, self.width, self.height))
        
        self.button_frames += 1
        pygame.display.update()
        return
    
    pass
```

The method of counting frames and comparing that with the FPS to prevent multi-detection of a single click, is a more easier and efficient approach, since the click delay will adjust itself according to the game's FPS in realtime, which would not have been the case if a timed approach would have been used.